# Can dead pixels appear with age of an LCD?

Tags: display, lcd, dead-pixel

I'm curious if it's common for dead pixels to have more of a chance of appearing as it ages. I have a 3 year old laptop and just noticed 3 dead pixels in one corner. I don't believe I've noticed them before.

Just curious if this is normal. Not saying dead pixels are normal, but asking if the chances of them happening in older screens is more likely. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course pixels can die during the lifespan of a screen. Pixels (rather sub-pixels) are controlled by transistors and of course like any other electronic device they can get broken over time.
Usually there are only several sub-pixels dying. This means the pixel seems to appear in permanent color.

The same applies (even more commonly) to the backlight which is subject to dim over its lifespan.

Sorry to say so but there is usually no way to repair such defects. Before replacing the screen make sure to test with another screen in order to assure it's not your video memory which has broken down and causing image artifacts.

Comment: Actually there are ways that might fix dead transistors, this is by triggering them lots of times in a short time span. There are programs available that you'll have to run for half a day and might fix dead sub-pixels.